# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: x and y values are 2 data types

Tags: python, decision-tree, iris-dataset

I am trying to train a very simple model using DecisionTreeClassifier().

iris.csv is my dataset.

```
dtc1 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc1.fit(x1Train,y1Train)
predicted1 = dtc1.predict(x1Test)
predicted1
```

[data shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ov9b.png)

The error I am getting is,
[ValueError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPgIA.png)

Is this because my training x and y are numeric and strings??
How can I solve this?

I have tried to convert my x1, y1, and x1Train, y1Train to `to_numpy()` but the same issue occurs.

Edit: Tried according to the comments.

```
x1Train.values.reshape(1,-1)
y1Train.values.reshape(1,-1)
dtc1.fit([x1Train],[y1Train]) #this line runs
predicted1 = dtc1.predict(x1Test.reshape(-1,1)) #this line gives error
predicted1
```

Error getting
[AttributeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWGKJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you should do

```py
dtc1 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc1.fit(x1Train,y1Train)
predicted1 = dtc1.predict(x1Test.reshape(-1,1))
predicted1
```

or

```py
dtc1 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc1.fit(x1Train,y1Train)
predicted1 = dtc1.predict(x1Test.reshape(1,-1))
predicted1
```

depending on your data.

Comment: I get the Value Error at this point ```dtc1.fit(x1Train,y1Train)```. Tried reshaping x1Train and y1Train. Did not work either.

Comment: @SasaniPerera you're getting an `AttributeError` now. That is because you are trying to use the method `reshape` to something that has no such method. It seems that `x1Test` is not a numpy array. Maybe you should convert it first. Something like `dtc1.predict(np.array(x1Test).reshape(-1,1))`

Answer (score 0):

So the actual issue was assigning data to x1 and y1. It should have been

```
x1 = iris[['SepalLengthCm']]
y1 = iris[['Species']]
```

rather than

```
x1 = iris['SepalLengthCm']
y1 = iris['Species']
```

Because we are getting data to a pandas DataFrame.